# Javascript regex: match an adress (number + name of the street)

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to use a regex in Javascript to match to a string that contains a number in 1st position **then** a street name, for instance:

**54 street Saint-Louis**

The regex I tried is like this: `var res = /[0-9]\s[A-Z]\s[A-Z-]/.test("8 street Saint-Louis");`

But it returns false...

Any idea?

Comment: You forgot to apply [quantifiiers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#quantifiers)

Comment: Also your regex is not case insensitive - add the `i` flag

Comment: Ok thank you, I ended with this `/[0-9]{1,3}\s[A-Z]*\s[A-Z-]*/i.test("8748 street Saint-Louis");` but how come it returns true as I limited the number of digits with {1,3} ?

Comment: Because you're not anchoring it; it's matching starting at the `7`.

Comment: @ThisIsMe because `[0-9]{1,3}` will start the match from `748` so use start anchor `^[0-9]` and i didn't know you still have doubts so in case please try to add your doubts into post

Comment: Type your regexp into regex101.com and **carefully** read the textual description it will give you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

issues :

`[A-Z]` : it will only match a single alphabet so use either `*` or `+`

your sample case include lowercase letters but your regex is only looking for uppercase so use `[a-zA-Z]`

so use `^\d+\s[a-zA-Z]+(\s[a-zA-Z-]*)?$`

`^\d+` : starts with one or more digits

`\s[a-zA-Z]+` : space then one or more alphabets

`(\s[a-zA-Z-]*)?` : `?` zero or one match of ,space and zero or more alphabets and `-` , `$` mean end of string match

[`Demo`](https://regex101.com/r/MH6SY9/3)

```js
console.log(/^\d+\s[a-zA-Z]+(\s[a-zA-Z-]*)?$/.test('8 street Saint-Louis')); 
console.log(/^\d+\s[a-zA-Z]+(\s[a-zA-Z-]*)?$/.test('8 street')); 
console.log(/^\d+\s[a-zA-Z]+(\s[a-zA-Z-]*)?$/.test('8748 street Saint-Louis')); 
//-----------------------------------------------------------

console.log(/^\d{1,3}\s[a-zA-Z]+(\s[a-zA-Z-]*)?$/.test('8748 street Saint-Louis'));
```

Comment: To clarify your comment "and `-` at end" -- a hyphen in the middle of the patterns means a range, `a-z` is "a through z".  At the end, it means a hyphen itself should be part of the characters matched.

Comment: @JamesCurran thanks to add clarity , i wanted to mention `$` by saying at the end :)